# How to represent the following query(mongodb) in java

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a JSON in MongoDB with the following structure:

```
{
    id:"_234234",
    "stationId":"ALM",
    "storageData": {

    }
}
```

To retrieve JSON with `storageData` equal to `null`, in MongoDB I query as:

```
db.collection.find({"storageData":{"$gt" : {}}})
```

It gives me list of JSON bodies with empty `storageData`. So how do I represent that in Java

```
BasicDBObject obj=new BasicDDBObject("storageData", new BasicDBObject("$gt",{}));
collection.find(obj);
```

I am getting an error near  `BasicDBObject("$gt",{}))...`

How do I represent `("$gt",{})` in Java??

Answer (score 0):

First understand that null is a valid value. This would be valid:

```
{
    id:"_234234",
    StationId:"ALM",
    StorageData: null 
}
```

and retrieving the document, asking for storagedata which is null would retrieve the doc with the id _234234.

If what you need is to check which documents DON'T have the key "storagedata" then use the $exist keyword or construct the query in this way:

```
db.yourcollection.find("this.storagedata == null")
```

I would do it via query, and not in Java because it would alleviate cpu time and memory.

Comment: I want to check the documents which have storagedata key with no values inside.Here storageData is a subdocument.

Comment: The question was pretty specific, you have just misinterpreted it. You should also never use a JavaScript construct to test in the way that you demonstrate as it will scan the whole collection or index without any bounds. The query as shown by the OP can lexically bind to an index.

Comment: You might consider it pretty specific. After all, you wrote it yourself, but consider your sentence: To retrieve JSON with storageData equal to null, in MongoDB I query as:

db.collection.find({"storageData":{"$gt" : {}}})

Answer (score 0):

All you want to to here is represent an empty object:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(
    "storageData", new BasicDBObject(
        "$gt",new BasicDBObject()
     )
);
```

Which of course produces the query:

```
{ "storageData" : { "$gt" : { } } }
```

So that's it, just call `BasicDBObject` without any arguments.